# Postgres function returns custom data set

Tags: stored-procedures, plpgsql, postgresql-9.2

Is there a way to create postgres stored function (using plpgsql to be able to set input parameters) that returns a custom data set?

I've tried to do something like this according to official manual:

```
CREATE FUNCTION extended_sales(p_itemno int)
RETURNS TABLE(quantity int, total numeric) AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY SELECT quantity, quantity * price FROM sales
                 WHERE itemno = p_itemno;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

but result is an array with only one column which contains type (quantity, total), but I need to get two column array with 'quantity' column and 'total' column.

Comment: You need to use `select * from extended_sales(...)`. Plus you don't need a PL/pgSQL function: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/d5aef/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a guess you're running:

```
SELECT extended_sales(1);
```

This will return a composite type column. If you want it expanded, you must instead run:

```
SELECT * FROM extended_sales(1);
```

Also, as @a_horse_with_no_name notes, a PL/pgSQL function is completely unnecessary here. Presumably this is a simplified example?

In future please include:

- Your PostgreSQL version; and
- The exact SQL you ran and the exact output you got

Comment: It definitely works right now.
I take into account your recommendations about db version and sql-script in future, thank you!